# Discovery Server in C (database with structs may be?)

Tags: c, database, sockets, structure

I am trying to develop a own server application in C( Discovery Server). When this Discovery Server runs, it should create a entry(table sort of structure, having the ID, ServerName,URL,Capability of the servers which register to it). Next I have a couple more servers which when run, registers to the DiscoveryServer.
When registered to the DiscoveryServer, it should update the structure with the necessary information. And when the server stops, the records should be removed.

Next there is a client, which needs to connect to the DiscoveryServer, and then should call a method / function which should give all the records of the servers registered( Table entries)

I am a beginner here. Is it possible to do this in C? or better to do in Object oriented language?

If in C, the struct will not be accessed outside from that system on which DiscoveryServer is running?
Please let me know.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: I suggest using C++, for object-oriented approach.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source implementation of a discovery server available on github for reference

https://github.com/open62541/open62541/tree/master/src/server

It is from the open62541 project (IIOT Industrial Internet of Things) **https://open62541.org/**